# Find location of directory 'x' number of directories up

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, filepath

Let's say I have a root directory 'x' number of directories up from the current directory. How can I find the full path to this root directory in python assuming 'x' can change and thus can't be hard-coded in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

levels_up = 1  # or whatever you want

current_dir = Path.cwd()
root = current_dir.parents[levels_up - 1]

print(root)
# /home   <-- one level up from my home directory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from os.path import abspath, join

def get_root(path, up_n):
    return abspath(join(path, join(['..'] * up_n)))
```

You might also consider using `realpath` instead of `abspath`, that will take care of resolving symbolic links too.